Lottie does not release memory on Android
I am using Lottie animations in my Android app, and I am facing a memory issue where Lottie does not seem to release memory properly even after the animation is canceled and cleared. Over time, this leads to significant memory usage and eventually out-of-memory errors.
Here are the steps I take to clean up Lottie resources in my onDestroy method:
override fun onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy()

  binding.lottieAnimation.apply {
    cancelAnimation()
    clearAnimation()
    removeAllAnimatorListeners()
    removeAllUpdateListeners()
    invalidate()
 }
   LottieCompositionFactory.clearCache(this@MyActivity)    

Despite this cleanup, Android's Memory Profiler shows that memory allocated to the Java heap keeps growing (as shown in the screenshot). Here's a snapshot of my profiler:

The memory usage is primarily in the Java heap, and I suspect that Lottie is either holding onto resources or not clearing cached animations.
